# Row-wise unions in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data frame that looks like so (and is copy-pasteable with `df=pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')`:

```
    user_nm    month    unique_ips  shifted_ips     halves  quarters    mo_pairs
    100118231   2   set([142.136])  set([])         h1  q1  p1
    100118231   3   set([142.136])  set([142.136])  h1  q1  p2
    100118231   6   set([108.0])    set([142.136])  h1  q2  p3
    100118231   7   set([108.0])    set([108.0])    h2  q3  p4
    100118231   8   set([142.136])  set([108.0])    h2  q3  p4
    100118231   9   set([142.136])  set([142.136])  h2  q3  p5
    100118231   10  set([142.136])  set([142.136])  h2  q4  p5
    100118231   11  set([142.136])  set([142.136])  h2  q4  p6
    100406016   3   set([50.192])   set([])         h1  q1  p2
    100406016   7   set([50.192])   set([50.192])   h2  q3  p4
```

for each user, I want to group by `halves` (or `quarters`, or `mo_pairs`) and get the union of `unique_ips` and `shifted_ips`.

I can groupby the fields like so:

```
In [265]: a=df.groupby(['user_nm','halves'])

In [266]: a.head()
Out[266]: 

            user_nm month   unique_ips  shifted_ips halves  quarters    mo_pairs
user_nm halves                              
100118231   h1  0   100118231   2   set([142.136])  set([]) h1  q1  p1
        1   100118231   3   set([142.136])  set([142.136])  h1  q1  p2
        2   100118231   6   set([108.0])    set([142.136])  h1  q2  p3
    h2  3   100118231   7   set([108.0])    set([108.0])    h2  q3  p4
        4   100118231   8   set([142.136])  set([108.0])    h2  q3  p4
        5   100118231   9   set([142.136])  set([142.136])  h2  q3  p5
        6   100118231   10  set([142.136])  set([142.136])  h2  q4  p5
        7   100118231   11  set([142.136])  set([142.136])  h2  q4  p6
100406016   h1  8   100406016   3   set([50.192])   set([]) h1  q1  p2
    h2  9   100406016   7   set([50.192])   set([50.192])   h2  q3  p4
```

However, when I attempt to union these rows, I get an error:

```
In [267]: a.apply(lambda x: x[2] & x[3], axis=1)
TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Ideally, I would like something like this:

```
                  unique_ips    shifted_ips
user_nm   halves        
100118231   h1  set([142.136, 108.0])   set([142.136])
100118231   h2  set([142.136,108.0])    set([142.136,108.0])
100406016   h1  set([50.192])           set([])
100406016   h2  set([50.192])           set([50.192])
```

I've also tried `set_index`, but that does not group the dataframe appropriately

```
b=df.set_index(['user_nm','halves'])
```

This seems like a relatively simple task, what am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer to this is you need to use `aggregate` method while reducing `groupyby` object [Pandas GroupBy Aggregate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation).

Now the following snippet should solve your problem

**Properly handling set while reading** : the elements were coming out as `str` and not `set`

```
df.unique_ips = df.unique_ips.apply(eval)
df.shifted_ips = df.shifted_ips.apply(eval)
```

**Doing the groupby**

```
grouped = df.groupby(['user_nm', 'halves'])
my_lambda = lambda x: reduce(set.union, x)
output = grouped.aggregate({'unique_ips': my_lambda,
                            'shifted_ips': my_lambda})
```

The result being:

```
                             unique_ips            shifted_ips
user_nm   halves                                              
100118231 h1      set([142.136, 108.0])         set([142.136])
          h2      set([142.136, 108.0])  set([142.136, 108.0])
100406016 h1              set([50.192])                set([])
          h2              set([50.192])          set([50.192])
```

Comment: thank you, knew I was making this harder than it needed to be.  back to the docs for me, thanks for the link.

Comment: great solution, for Python 3 you need to import reduce: `from functools import reduce`

Comment: Instead of dealing with `functools.reduce`, I'd recommend `my_lambda = lambda x: set.union(*x)`. According to the docs, this is available since Python 2.6.