# Use set union on a SeriesGroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, set-union

[image]

Suppose that I have a dataframe(df) like above, I want to run df.groupby(['id', 'client']) and the apply union on the items column ? 
The result should be one row  -> id = 1 and client = 70 items= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}.

I appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Union in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428108/set-union-in-pandas). Or perhaps this: [Row-wise unions in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020595/row-wise-unions-in-pandas-groupby). `df.groupby(['id', 'client']).agg(lambda x: functools.reduce(set.union, x))`

Comment: thank you @mcskinner, your suggestion is working!